# cannot find symbol InputStreamer

Tags: java, io

```
import java.io.*;
public class MgSq
{
    public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new 
public
InputStreamer(System.in));
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
    {

      int w, x, y, z, b, key;
      boolean n_ok;
      int [] [] square = new int [15] [15];
      {
         System.out.print("Size of square? ");
         b = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
     n_ok = (z<=b) & (b<=15+1) & (b%2==1);
         if ( n_ok )
      {
               for (w=0;w<b;w++)
               for (x=0;x<b;x++) square[w][x] = 0;
               square[0][(int)(b-1)/2] = 1;
               key = 2;
               w = 0;
               x = (int)(b-1)/2;
               while ( key <= b*b )
           {
           y = w - 1;
           if ( y < 0 ) y = y + b;
               z = x - 1;
           if ( z < 0 ) z = z + b;
               if ( square[y][z] != 0 ) w = (w+1) % b;
               else 
           { 
        w = y; x = z;
           }
               square[w][x] = key;
               key = key + 1;
           }
         System.out.println("Magic square of size " + b);
         for (w=0;w<b;w++)
            {
               for (x=0;x<b;x++)
                  System.out.print("\t"+square[w][x]);
               System.out.println();
            }
         }      

    }
         System.out.println("Error in number, try again.");
}
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
MgSq.java:4 error: cannot find symbol 
public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

symbol: class InputStreamer
class: MgSq
```

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: I'm very new at this, so I'm sorry if it's not properly formatted. But do please help me.

Comment: Your error message mentions a class that's not mentioned in the quoted line above the error message but mentioned in your original code: `InputStreamer`. Also, that class does not exist and you probably wanted to use `InputStream` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Since you import only `java.io.*`, `InputStreamer` is probably a typo and you wanted to use `InputStream` instead.

Answer (score 1):

That second `public` in the following line doesn't make sense:

```
public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new 
public 
InputStreamer(System.in));
```

change it to

```
public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamer(System.in));
```

and apparently `InputStreamer` isn't actually a class.  as other people said, try `InputStreamReader` or `InputStream`

Comment: @AchintyaJha googling `java InputStreamer` gives no results

Comment: You suggested OP InputStreamer(System.in).

Comment: @AchintyaJha I can't find the documentation for `InputStreamer` can you?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `public` from before `new InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `InputStreamer` to `InputStreamReader`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new 
public
InputStreamer(System.in));
```

should be

```
public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```